# What do you think about additional markup inside of Hx-Headings?

Tags: html, heading

What do you think, and why, about additional HTML-markup inside of Hx-headings? Does it influence in any way the SEO?

I.e.

**Example 1**

```
<h1>
    <div>
        <span>Find the best</span>
        <span>real estate consultant</span>
        <span>in your city</span>
    </div>
</h1>
```

vs.

**Example 2**

```
<h1>Find the best real estate consultant in your city</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an SEO perspective? Providing there's no attempt at obfuscation (using the additional markup to disguise keyword stuffing for example), then in my experience the only potential issue is that an H1 with additional markup is likely to be longer than is sensible to achieve a keyword focus. Aside from that, tests I've run by adding or removing additional markup to H1 tags has had no measurable effect on SEO.

From a UX perspective? I've never noticed that additional markup would cause UX issues, even in terms of accessibility (specifically screen readers and the like).

From a working perspective, it is something I try to avoid or keep to a minimum. But I recognise that this is a personal preference as I try to keep my code as simple as I can.

Strictly speaking, you should only use inline tags within a heading tag, but it's not something that a modern browser would render improperly.

Comment: I've got this use case to see and the question to answer from people, who used this additional markup inside of H1 only for layout and styling purposes. My opinion is fully equalling with your: headings should contain text, nothing more.